# C# Webbrowser Control Find Out 200 & 204 HTTP Respone URL

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I need help trying to find out the urls of web-browsers http responses after I navigate to a web-page and click on a button (this button is a download button) and if you check via fiddler I can see other Requests/Respones (200 & 204) I would like to be get those URLS to string.

I have one idea that works with httpwebrequests I just check the last referrer when I need and I get the last http request/response even If didn't execute it manually it server/browser side of things I don't control it if you understand what I mean.

Do you guys know how can I get this done in a web-browser control? Thanks!